# Converting String to BigDecimal When String Contains 'e' Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

**Note:** I have asked this question when I was a newbie to programming in java. I have got the solution for the same; back then itself. Editing to make it clear for other readers.

**Input Format:** Input is in string format. In our case we assume to convert the strings that contains only digits to BigDecimal, rest of them can be ignored.

> Eg: We expect *1e4 -> BigDecimal value* to be passed as "10000". So, the inputs which
>   contains alphabets or any other special characters can be be ignored to convert.

**Reason for the requirement:** We need to search few columns in the DB based on the search text and retrieve rows on matching criteria. Lets say columns name(VarChar column), price(Decimal column), type (VarChar column). So, if the search text can be converted to BigDecimal we will search if text matches any of the columns else if it can't be converted to BigDecimal we will search if the text matches other two columns.

---

Without analysing the input further I have blindly converted the search text to BigDecimal.

**Example:** if the name in DB is 1e3 and price is 10000 and if search text is 1e4, then the converted BigDecimal value of 1e4 will be matched to 10000 and will fetch the row.

**Initial Code of converting to BigDecimal:**

```
   BigDecimal textToBigDecimal = null;
    try
    {
       textToBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(searchText);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ignored)
    {
    }
    if (textToBigDecimal == null)
    {
      //criteria handling code.
    }
    else
    {
      //criteria handling code.
    }
```

Skipped the criteria constructed code. Added try-catch because, the input can be a pure string also. Based on that criteria construction differs.

**Modified Code:**

```
 BigDecimal textToBigDecimal = null;
    try
    {
      if (!searchText.contains("e") && !searchText.contains("E"))
      {
         textToBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(searchText);
      }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ignored)
    {
    }
    if (textToBigDecimal == null)
    {
      //criteria handling code.
    }
    else
    {
      //criteria handling code.
    }
```

**Note:** If any further doubts pls comment on the question. I have posted this question expecting to find a default java method that converts only the strings that contains digits only to BigDecimal and throws exception for rest of the strings.

Comment: I couldn't understand, what is the issue? Can you please share your code and the full stack trace of all exceptions you get?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - in particular, by "But I wont throw exception" do you mean you *want* to throw an exception, or you want an exception *not* to be thrown? A [mcve] would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: `new BigDecimal("45e57")` will convert to `4.5E+58` which is correct! What do you want to prevent? What to achieve?

Comment: I don't want to convert 45e57 to 4.5E+58. Instead, throw error.

Comment: @Finnismissing What is the logic behind that? I mean, if anything different from number and point is found, an exception should be thrown?

Comment: I mean convert rest of the strings to BigDecimal, except strings which contain e.

Comment: @Finnismissing use [String#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) to check if the provided string contains `e`.

Comment: As @BackSlash says: just inspect the string if it contains `e` or `E` and reject those strings. You can pass all others to BigDecimal. I don't quite see the problem. All other unwanted characters will be rejected by BigDecimal anyway.

Comment: I have updated the question. Pls re-visit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exception to be thrown for strings like `'45e57'`, you can use for example `Long.parseLong("43e57")` before constructing `BigDecimal`. It will throw `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Why a try-catch if you can just check if there is an `e` inside the given string?

Comment: We doesn't know if those string values contain something else except `e`. But the question needs much more detailed description: what kind of string values we have etc

Comment: True, but for everything else the `BigDecimal` throws an exception itself. The only difference between `long` and `BigDecimal` is that `long` doesn't accept `E` while `BigDecimal` does, so in this case checking for the `E` is just fine.

Comment: Some values may be decimal values. So, I can't use Long.

Comment: As @BackSlash said, you can simply use [String#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) to check your string value

Comment: @BackSlash I have updated the question. Pls look into it.